# Rectification of 601 network error in sim900a GSM

Tags: http, arduino-uno, gsm, arduino-ide, sim900

I am working with gsm SIM900a module and trying to send data to web server through that. Everything works fine. For every HTTP commands I am getting response as OK. But when it comes to AT+HTTPACTION=1 , it is giving me result as 1,601,0.

I tried to increase delay time between the commands and also the timeout.

```
 Serial.println("HTTP post method :");

Serial.print("AT\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT"); 

  delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData(); 

  delay(5000);



  Serial.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\""); 

  delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet\"\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet\"");  

  delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("AT+SAPBR=1,1\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1"); 

  delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("AT+SAPBR=2,1\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1"); 

 delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("AT+HTTPINIT\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPINIT");  
  delay(5000); 

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");  

  delay(10000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(10000);
```

After this I am giving the AT+HTTPPARA and passing the URL:

```
Serial.print("AT+HTTPDATA=100,30000\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPDATA=100,30000");

  delay(10000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(10000);

  Serial.print("{\"temperature\":\"20.00\" ,\"humidity\":\"10.00\" , \"recordedTime\":[2019-08-12,01:25:00] , \"latitude\":\"15.67\" , \"longitude\":\"50.00\" , \"deviceId\":\"1\" , \"macAddress\":\"A\"}");
  SIM900.println("{\"temperature\":\"20.00\" ,\"humidity\":\"10.00\" , \"recordedTime\":[2019-08-12,01:25:00] , \"latitude\":\"15.67\" , \"longitude\":\"50.00\" , \"deviceId\":\"1\" , \"macAddress\":\"A\"}");

  delay(10000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(10000);

  Serial.print("AT+HTTPACTION=1\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");  

  delay(10000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(10000);

  Serial.print("AT+HTTPTERM\\r\\n");  

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPTERM"); 

  delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("AT+SAPBR=0,1\\r\\n");

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1"); 

  delay(5000);

  ShowSerialData();

  delay(5000);
```

Comment: When you get a couple of minutes, please take the time to learn the formatting tools here, so that you can present code/logs/console information in a readable fashion. See my edit.

Comment: Ok..but can you try to answer the actual question here??